# Show Button after ajax function success

Tags: ajax

I want to show a button "Reload Game" after function success instead of this bootstrapDialog box

I need this button to fit over my  `<div class="tilting"></div>`     Instead of showing somewhere else on page

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide a part of code where you call ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below code inside the success method,

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("tilting")[0].innerHTML="<button type="button">Reload Game</button>";
```

If you are using jQuery Ajax try it below way,

```
  function loadDoc() {
    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'APUC',
     data: 'productName=' + productName,
     dataType: 'html',
     cache: false,
     success: function (result) {
         document.getElementsByClassName("tilting")[0].innerHTML="<button type="button">Reload Game</button>";
        },
     });
}
```

If you are using pure Ajax, try it like this:

```
function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

         document.getElementsByClassName("tilting")[0].innerHTML="<button type="button">Reload Game</button>";

        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```